# Why the output is not logic?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```js
let vacationSpots = ['USA', 'UK', 'Colombia']; 

 for (let vacationSpotIndex = vacationSpots.length - 1; vacationSpotIndex >=  0; vacationSpotIndex-- ) {
   console.log('I would love to visit '  + vacationSpots[vacationSpotIndex]);
 }
```

I suppose the length is 3 and we subtract 1 so it equals to 2;
so the index start is 2 and we substract 1 on every loop
the probleme in the condition 
vacationSpotIndex >=  0
I suppose logicly it is  vacationSpotIndex <=  0

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Please take a few minutes to help us help you by reading [ask]. You really haven't explained your problem or what exactly it is you expect this code to do differently than what it currently does

Comment: _“I suppose logically it is `vacationSpotIndex <= 0`”_ — No, it’s not. Read the [docs on `for` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/for). The condition `vacationSpotIndex <= 0` would cause the loop to never execute, since an index can’t be negative.

Comment: His condition is checking an integer with no array. So, there is no index. Just cause it has the name "Index" doesn't mean it's an array's index. It's an integer.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but it seems like your question is, why is it `vacationSpotIndex >= 0` instead of `vacationSpotIndex <= 0`?  The answer is, a for loop's condition is checked before each iteration of the loop.  What you're saying is, "run this loop *as long as* `vacationSpotIndex >= 0`."  Once that condition isn't true anymore, the loop will stop running.  So it will count down 2, 1, 0, -1, and then because -1 is not greater than or equal to zero, the loop will stop.

Comment: What is the different between your answer and my answer

Comment: @Osama Your code leaves off the first item of the array.  The OP's code was right (I think, the question is not super clear).  I thought OP was just looking for an explanation of why it works, and that's what I answered.

Answer (score 0):

> **Index of Array start from 0 in javaScript**

Every thing in working correctly.Nothing is wrong here.

```
let vacationSpots = ['USA', 'UK', 'Colombia']; 
    vacationSpots.length=3
    index->0='USA'
    index->1='UK'
    index-2='Colombia'
```

**for (let vacationSpotIndex = vacationSpots.length - 1; vacationSpotIndex >=  0; vacationSpotIndex-- ) {**

> **`vacationSpotIndex >= 0;` 
>   this condition says iterate the loop till vacationSpotIndex is greater then or equal to zero and this is checked just before every iterarion.**

loop will start from index=2 and it will go till index=0

```
vacationSpotIndex=2
vacationSpotIndex=1
vacationSpotIndex=0
```

Answer (score -3):

While you use >=0 so it will continue looping when it is 0 so result in out of range (-1) make it just >0

```
let vacationSpots = ['USA', 'UK', 'Colombia']; 
 for (let vacationSpotIndex = vacationSpots.length - 1; vacationSpotIndex > 0; vacationSpotIndex-- ) {
   console.log('I would love to visit '  +        vacationSpots[vacationSpotIndex]);
  }
```

Comment: It will loop when =0 then 0-1 then vacationSpots[-1]

Comment: Answer makes no sense